# show the names of all suppliers that appear more than once in the supplies table

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have 2 tables supplies and supplier, i need to print names of all suppliers that appear more than once in the supplies table I tried use the follow code:

```
SELECT name FROM SUPPLIER
WHERE supplier.supplierNum = supplies.supplerNum
having count(supplierNum) > 1;
```

but the code i=didn't work.
here its the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE supplies (
  supplierNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  partNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  quantity SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (supplierNum, partNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (supplierNum) REFERENCES supplier (supplierNum),
  FOREIGN KEY (partNum) REFERENCES parts (partNum)
);

CREATE TABLE supplier (
  supplierNum CHAR(2)   NOT NULL,
  name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  status TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (supplierNum)
);
```

Comment: review joins https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html and alias https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 0):

Count the occurrence in `supplies` table first then `join` it with `supplier`:

```
SELECT sp.name
FROM supplier AS sp
INNER JOIN 
  (
  SELECT distinct supplierNum 
  FROM supplies
  GROUP BY supplierNum
  HAVING COUNT(supplierNum) > 1
  ) as cnt
 ON sp.supplierNum = cnt.supplierNum;
```

Demo in *db<>fiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9c8c57314858b2955f7d62de69a5cd4e)